# Proof about invertible if 0 is not an eigenvalue of T.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, linear-transformations, determinant

Prove that a linear operator T on a finite-dimensional vector space is invertible if and only if zero is not an eigenvalue of T.

proof: 
$\Rightarrow$: let $v \in V$, then $T(v)=\lambda v$. Since T is invertible, it is injective, so by definition, T(v)=0,

> Question: I am not sure what to argue after that, some definitions to think about?

$\Leftarrow$: If zero is not an eigenvalue of T,then...

> Question: I was told to think of $T-\lambda I$, a linear mapping. But not sure how to utilize.

Thanks@

Comment: If  $\lambda =0$ were an eigenvalue, then there would be a  $v\neq 0$ satisfying  $Tv=0$, a contradiction to the injectivity of $T$.

Comment: If T is invertible, then $T(v)=0$ has only the solution $v=0$, as $T(v)=0$ implies $v=T^{-1}T(v)=T^{-1}(0)=0$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby can you expand on this, I don't get "there would be a $v \neq 0$ satisfying Tv=0"

Comment: @neveryield If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then there is a nonzero $v$ satisfying  $Tv=\lambda v $(by definition). In your case, take $\lambda =0$.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Thanks for reminding of that, let me try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One doesn't need to use determinants or look too closely at $T - \lambda I$ to address this, to wit:

Let

$T \in \mathcal L(V), \tag 0$

with

$\dim V < \infty, \tag{0.5}$

and suppose that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$; then $T$ is injective; for if

$v_1, v_2 \in V \tag 1$

with

$Tv_1 = Tv_2, \tag 2$

then

$T(v_1 - v_2) = Tv_1 - Tv_2 = 0 = 0(v_1 - v_2);  \tag 3$

thus if

$v_1 - v_2 \ne 0, \tag 4$

$v_1 - v_2$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $0$, contrary to hypothesis; therefore

$v_1 - v_2 = 0 \Longrightarrow v_1 = v_2, \tag 5$

establishing the injectivity of $T$; in light of (0.5) we see that $T$ is also surjective; hence $T$ is a linear isomorphism of $V$, and is invertible.

We next assume that $T$ is invertible, and that

$Tv = \lambda v, \; v \ne 0; \tag 6$

in this event we may write

$0 \ne v = Iv = T^{-1}Tv = T^{-1} (\lambda v) = \lambda T^{-1}v \tag 7$

then clearly

$\lambda \ne 0, \tag 8$

and we are done.